# angular checkbox with off screen input tag

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Issue in Angular checkbox! Any help would be appreciated:

**html**:

```
<span for="check" tabindex="0" role="checkbox" (click)="inputCheck.click()" (keydown)="keyEvent()">
    <label for="check">checkbox</label>
    <input type="checkbox" style="display: none" id="check" (change)="changeEvent($event)" data-toggle="toggle" #inputCheck />
</span>
```

When i click the span(not the label, consider span looks like a rectangle in which it has the label Checkbox), i get single click event, but when i click the label, i get 2 click events and at that time it is not acting as a checkbox.

Need help on this. **I need to either click the span/label, i need to get only one click event to make the checkbox either checked or not checked.**

Thanks in Advance!

**component**:

```
changeEvent(event) {
    console.log("change Event : " + event.target.checked);
}

clickEvent() {
    console.log("click Event");
}

keyEvent() {
    console.log("key event");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

[basic example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h4huct)

HTML:

```
<span for="check" tabindex="0" role="checkbox" (click)="inputCheck.click()" (keydown)="keyEvent()">

<input type="checkbox" style="display: none" id="check" (change)="changeEvent($event)" data-toggle="toggle" #inputCheck />
</span>

<label for="check">checkbox</label>
```

Comment: please accept the solution so others can find it easily. thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Build the HTML as follows:-

```
<span for="check" tabindex="0" role="checkbox" (click)="inputCheck.click()" (keydown)="keyEvent()"></span>


<label for="check">checkbox</label>


<input type="checkbox" style="display: none" id="check" (change)="changeEvent($event)" data-toggle="toggle" #inputCheck />
```

In your code, the label is also working as desired and then the click event propagates to the span element and hence it also fires.

Hence, do not have `span` wrap your label / checkbox elements